# Simple javascript canvas framework for navigating large 2D graph?

Tags: javascript, canvas, frameworks, html5-canvas

I have a large graph (1000+ nodes, 5000+ edges) that I'd like to display on an HTML canvas. I would like to have the ability to zoom in to a single node, or zoom out to view the entire graph. I would rather not implement these functions myself with the native API, so I am looking for a simple javascript canvas framework that will allow me to attach generic objects to a zoomable 2D map. Does such a framework exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) and it has capabilities to render dense graph . It provides high level API for zoom in /out .